# Decode URI path segment form name:tom

Tags: android, url

If I have a url: http://www.test.com/segment1/segment2/name:tom/segment4/

What is the best way to set a variable equal to "tom"? I figure there's a method that I'm unaware of. For now I'm just parsing but if a method is optimized to do this I'd rather use that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the url will always be formatted the same parsing is probably fine.

```
//Parse name from url
public String getName(String url){
    String[] spliturl = url.split(":");
    String[] arrayofnames = spliturl[1].split("/"); //Segment after the semicolon
    return arrayofnames[0]; //But before the /
}
```

How are you doing it currently?

Comment: Currently just like that, splitting with the ':' and then reading from the returned array.